# Can i run nightly and stable compliers?

Tags: rust, nightly-build

I am on rust stable, but i am trying to use rocket. I don’t think it works on the stable complier. Can i run both the nightly and stable complier on my system?

Comment: I believe I saw that Rocket will be able to run on stable when 1.45 or 1.46 hits.

Comment: Use nightly for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use [rustup](https://rustup.rs/), you can have both toolchains on your system. You can use `rustup install nightly` to install nightly, then you can use `rustup default nightly/stable` to change which version of `rustc` is used. You can also use `rustup run nightly/stable rustc` to run `rustc` as one version without changing the default.

Comment: I installed nightly and made it my default .It works now. Thanks. 